# Consider defining a bean named 'entityManagerFactory' in your configuration SpringBoot

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, spring-mvc, spring-boot

```
package com.loginregister.loginregister.entities;

import java.util.List;

import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.ManyToMany;

@Entity
public class Role {

    @Id
    private String name;
    @ManyToMany(mappedBy = "roles")
    private List<User> users;

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public List<User> getUsers() {
        return users;
    }

    public void setUsers(List<User> users) {
        this.users = users;
    }

    public Role(String name, List<User> users) {
        this.name = name;
        this.users = users;
    }

    public Role() {
    }

    public Role(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

}
```

Role.java

```
package com.loginregister.loginregister.entities;

import javax.persistence.*;
import javax.validation.constraints.NotEmpty;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.JoinColumn;
import javax.persistence.ManyToOne;



@Entity
public class Task {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    private Long id;
    @NotEmpty
    private String date;
    @NotEmpty
    private String startTime;
    @NotEmpty
    private String stopTime;
    @NotEmpty
    private String Description;
    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "USER_EMAIL")
    private User user;

    public Long getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(Long id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getDate() {
        return date;
    }

    public void setDate(String date) {
        this.date = date;
    }

    public String getStartTime() {
        return startTime;
    }

    public void setStartTime(String startTime) {
        this.startTime = startTime;
    }

    public String getStopTime() {
        return stopTime;
    }

    public void setStopTime(String stopTime) {
        this.stopTime = stopTime;
    }

    public String getDescription() {
        return Description;
    }

    public void setDescription(String description) {
        Description = description;
    }

    public User getUser() {
        return user;
    }

    public void setUser(User user) {
        this.user = user;
    }

    public Task(String date, String startTime, String stopTime, String description, User user) {
        this.date = date;
        this.startTime = startTime;
        this.stopTime = stopTime;
        Description = description;
        this.user = user;
    }

    public Task(String date, String startTime, String stopTime, String description) {
        this.date = date;
        this.startTime = startTime;
        this.stopTime = stopTime;
        Description = description;
    }

    public Task() {
    }
}
```

Task.java

```
package com.loginregister.loginregister.entities;

import org.springframework.scheduling.config.Task;

import javax.persistence.*;
import javax.validation.constraints.Email;
import javax.validation.constraints.NotEmpty;
import javax.validation.constraints.Size;
import javax.persistence.Column;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.JoinColumn;
import java.util.List;
import javax.persistence.JoinTable;
import javax.persistence.ManyToMany;
import javax.persistence.OneToMany;



@Entity
public class User {

    @Id
    @Email
    @NotEmpty
    @Column(unique = true)
    private String email;
    @NotEmpty
    private String name;
    @Size(min = 4)
    private String password;
    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "user", cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    private List<Task> tasks;
    @ManyToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    @JoinTable(name = "USER_ROLES",joinColumns = {
            @JoinColumn(name = "USER_EMAIL", referencedColumnName = "email")
    },inverseJoinColumns = {@JoinColumn(name = "ROLE_NAME", referencedColumnName = "name")})
    private List<Role> roles;

    public String getEmail() {
        return email;
    }

    public void setEmail(String email) {
        this.email = email;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public String getPassword() {
        return password;
    }

    public void setPassword(String password) {
        this.password = password;
    }

    public List<Task> getTasks() {
        return tasks;
    }

    public void setTasks(List<Task> tasks) {
        this.tasks = tasks;
    }

    public List<Role> getRoles() {
        return roles;
    }

    public void setRoles(List<Role> roles) {
        this.roles = roles;
    }

    public User(String email, String name, String password) {
        this.email = email;
        this.name = name;
        this.password = password;
    }

    public User() {

    }
}
```

User.java

```
package com.loginregister.loginregister.repositories;

import com.loginregister.loginregister.entities.Role;
import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.JpaRepository;

public interface RoleRepository  extends JpaRepository<Role, String>{

}
```

RoleRepository.java

```
package com.loginregister.loginregister.repositories;

import com.loginregister.loginregister.entities.Task;
import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.JpaRepository;

public interface TaskRepository extends JpaRepository<Task, Long> {


}
```

TaskRepository.java

```
package com.loginregister.loginregister.repositories;

import com.loginregister.loginregister.entities.User;
import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.JpaRepository;

public interface UserRepository extends JpaRepository<User, String> {

}
```

UserRepository

```
package com.loginregister.loginregister;

import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;

@SpringBootApplication
public class LoginRegisterApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(LoginRegisterApplication.class, args);
    }
}
```

LoginRegisterApplication.java

```
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/SpringAuth?useSSL=false

spring.datasource.username=root
spring.datasource.password=****

spring.jpa.show-sql=true
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=create-drop
```

application.properties

http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    4.0.0

```
<groupId>com.LoginRegister</groupId>
<artifactId>login-register</artifactId>
<version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
<packaging>jar</packaging>

<name>login-register</name>
<description>Demo project for Spring Boot</description>

<parent>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <version>2.0.3.RELEASE</version>
    <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
</parent>

<properties>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>
    <java.version>1.8</java.version>
</properties>

<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-security</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-thymeleaf</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-devtools</artifactId>
        <scope>runtime</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>mysql</groupId>
        <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
        <scope>runtime</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-security-test</artifactId>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
        <version>5.0.7.Final</version>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>

<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

pom.xml

[ERROR] Tests run: 1, Failures: 0, Errors: 1, Skipped: 0, Time elapsed: 2.941 s <<< FAILURE! - in com.loginregister.loginregister.LoginRegisterApplicationTests
[ERROR] contextLoads(com.loginregister.loginregister.LoginRegisterApplicationTests)  Time elapsed: 0.005 s  <<< ERROR!
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Failed to load ApplicationContext
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'entityManagerFactory' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/orm/jpa/HibernateJpaConfiguration.class]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is org.hibernate.AnnotationException: @OneToOne or @ManyToOne on com.loginregister.loginregister.entities.Task.user references an unknown entity: com.loginregister.loginregister.entities.User
Caused by: org.hibernate.AnnotationException: @OneToOne or @ManyToOne on com.loginregister.loginregister.entities.Task.user references an unknown entity: com.loginregister.loginregister.entities.User

Comment: Remove the `hibernate-core` dependency.

Comment: thank you but there is another problem

Comment: I edited the new error text in the question

Comment: You are referencing the wrong `Task` check the message. `org.springframework.scheduling.config.Task` instead of your own actual entity.

Comment: I've fixed the error and added the new error text

Comment: thank you very much, help me solve the problem. remove this reference "org.springframework.scheduling.config.Task"

Answer (score 0):

This can be resolved by :

Hibernate jpa 2.1 jar which is a part of spring-boot-started-data-jpa. Remove dependencies in .m2 folder and again report pom.xml

OR`<dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
</dependency>`
Add Repository Annotation